# Vertex cannot switch to another group

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Consider a complete graph with $n$ vertices. Each edge has value $1$ or $-1$ with probability 50% each. For any partition of vertices into groups, the score of a vertex is the sum of the value of its edges to the remaining vertices in its group. Let $p_n$ be the probability that for some partition, no vertex can switch to another group or form a singleton group to obtain a better score. Does $p_n\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

One idea is to look at whether the trivial partition of putting all vertices in one group satisfies the condition. However, when we put all vertices in one group and $n$ is large, some vertex will likely have negative score, so it can get a better score by forming a singleton group.

Comment: Boneheaded question: isn't $p_n$ always $0$? Take all of the vertices to be in singleton groups; the only edge weighting such that no vertex can improve its score by forming a doubleton is if all edges are $-1$. But in that case, take all singleton groups except one doubleton: each of the vertices in the doubleton has negative score so can improve by becoming a singleton. Am I misunderstanding the quantifiers?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the quantifiers. $p_n$ is the probability that for **some** partition, no vertex can obtain a better score by switching. Even though the partition with all singleton groups is unlikely to satisfy this, there could be some other partition that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that an origin of your problem is some contest and the author introduced the probability into the problem in order to make it seemingly harder. :-) But we shall not follow him and show that  $p_n=1$ by proving that for *any* fixed distribution of $\pm 1$ at the edges there exists a partition in which no vertex can switch to another group or form a singleton group to obtain a better score. Indeed, the total score of the partition (the sum of scores of all vertices)  is twice the sum of values of the edges not cut by the partition. It remains to remark that the  total score may attain only finitely many values and when we switch a vertex to another group or form from it a singleton group to obtain a better score, we also increase the total score.

Comment: @pi66 I defined the total score of the partition as the sum of scores of all vertices.